# Calling c program from different Android project

Tags: java, android, c, android-ndk, .so

I am using Android Studio version - 2.1.2. I have created one project in Android -  **MyNdk**. This project uses c program. The c progarm has a function 
**getCountry**(). This function is created in the file **torento.c**. 
Function is like this -

```
Java_com_myndk_MainActivity_getCountry(JNIEnv *env, jobject instance) **{**

   // TODO
   //return (*env)->NewStringUTF(env, returnValue);

   return (*env)->NewStringUTF(env, "Canada");

**}**
```

In the java  file,  I have used this code to load the  library, System.loadLibrary("torento"). **libtorento.so** is created 
successfully under jni folder for all devices. So far no problem, I can call the c program with out any error.

Now I have created second project - **HelloAndroidJni**. This project also uses c program. I want to use the **getCountry**() from **libtorento.so**.
This project has the c program **paris.c**, which is created under jni folder. For this project the library is **libparis.so**. 
Now I have created a folder **jniLibs**, under which I have copied **libtorento.so** from the first project for all device.  Then I have loaded the  libraries using the following
code in java file.

```
static
{
    System.loadLibrary("torento");
    System.loadLibrary("paris");

}
```

libtorento.so is loaded successfully in HelloAndroidJni project. I have checked .apk file. **libtorento.so** exists in the .apk file.

My question is how will I call the **getCountry()**  in the **HelloAndroidJni** project . I have searched lot, everywhere tutorial/sample is given
where c program is called from the same java project, where it is defined.
 Please help me.

*In Android Studio( 2.1.2), system generated jni folder and c file. No header file is created.*

Comment: This is not directly related to the Android, but take a look here: http://jnicookbook.owsiak.org/recipe-No-001/

Answer (score 0):

In the second project, you should create a new Java class com.myndk.MainActivity (I know t is not in the same Java package as the main activity for the new project). You can copy the MainActivity.java file from the myNdk project, or simply create a new one. The only requirement is that that class has defined the native method get country().

Now you can use this method in your new app.

Answer (score 0):

following your instruction, I have made this in **HelloAndroidJni**.  Have I done right ? My class is as follows

package com.dsc.bandhan.helloandroidjni;

@SuppressWarnings("JniMissingFunction")
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
TextView txtName;


static
{
    System.loadLibrary("torento");
    System.loadLibrary("paris");

}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    txtName=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtName);

    txtName.setText(getCountry());


}


public native String getCountry();
```

}

It is not working. It shows the following error
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Native method not found: com.dsc.bandhan.helloandroidjni.MainActivity.getCountry:()Ljava/lang/String;

Comment: I wrote this explicitly, but somehow this got lost: native method getCountry should be defined in class MainActivity in package com.myndk, not in package com.dsc.bandhan.helloandroidjni.

Comment: I have already defined getCountry() in MainActivity of package com.myndk. There it is working fine and libtorento.so file is also generated for all device successfully. In my second project System.loadLibrary("torento") is loaded with no error but I cannot call getCountry().

Comment: Exactly. The second project does not see the MainActivity class of the first project. This is why you cannot call its getCountry(). You can make the MainActivity class of the first project available for the second project, or you can cheat and only provide a small part of its interface for the second project.

Comment: Alex, thanks a lot. It is working. I have  made a class in the first project which include the native function and method, from the method I have called the native function. Then I have made the jar file. In the second project I have included that jar file and call the method of the class. Earlier I thought , I can directly call the native function from the .so file using some qualifier. Can't it be done that way ? Here if I have 10 native function, I have to define 10 method in the class. Have I worked in right direction?

Comment: JAR is a perfectly reasonable solution. Actually, it's even better to use an AAR: another form of archive that can contain both compiled Java classes and native code (in form of .so files). Android Studio (its gradle plugin) can take an AAR file for a library and put the .so files in the resulting APK file correctly for you.